# Learning Discrete Math with the "wrong" book

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm currently taking a discrete mathematics course at my school that is using the Johnsonbaugh book (by the way, is this a good book?).

The thing is, I've already kind started reading another Discrete Mathematics book written by Epps during the winter.  I'm kind of already well into the book already.

I really want to finish the Epp book, but it's really a buzz kill if I'm reading two discrete mathematics book at the same time.

So my question is, should I just switch over to the Johnsonbaugh book (which I REALLY don't like), or just keep reading the Epp book?  I feel like reading the Epp book will kind of put me at a disadvantage in class though.

Comment: This might be offtopic on stackoverflow. Not really programming is it? :)   http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: There's a site for this: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am beginning to think SO will starve of interesting questions. Some topics from the Epp's book are : 6. Counting
7. Functions
8. Recursion
9. O-Notation and the Efficiency of Algorithms
10. Relations
11. Graphs and Trees
12. Finite State Automata and Applications ... HOW THIS COULD BE  OFF TOPIC HERE ??

Comment: Epp's book is way better. But switching books or not depends on your school's "openness".